# ObjectBox IllegalStateException: Store is closed, Re-Open BoxStore

Tags: java, android, objectbox

I am using `ObjectBox` version **1.5.0**

Here is the method to delete all the data from the database.

```
public static void clearAllData(){
    mApp.getBoxStore().close();
    mApp.getBoxStore().deleteAllFiles();
}
```

I want to delete all the data from ObjectBox when user press on Logout button. Above method is deleting all the data but again when I want to add data I'm getting

```
IllegalStateException: Store is closed
```

**Problem:** How to re-open closed `BoxStore` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-call this line before adding data in `ObjectBox` (Correct me if there is better solution )

```
boxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().androidContext(this).build();
```

**Long Answer:**

**In the `Application` Class**

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {

    public static BaseApplication mInstance;
    private BoxStore boxStore;

    public static synchronized BaseApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mInstance = this;

        initializeBoxStore();
    }

    public BoxStore getBoxStore() {
        /* From this method we can get always opened BoxStore */
        if (boxStore != null && boxStore.isClosed())
            initializeBoxStore();
        return boxStore;
    }

    private void initializeBoxStore() {
        boxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().androidContext(this).build();
    }
}
```

**In `clearAllData` Method**

```
public static void clearAllData(){
        BoxStore boxStore = mApp.getBoxStore();
        boxStore.close();
        boxStore.deleteAllFiles();
}
```

This solved my problem.